# On Using Thanks a Pile

Tags: phrase-usage

As a non-native speaker of English, I am not quite sure whether or not I can use the phrase ***Thanks a pile*** to tell someone I am pleased for something good they have done.

Is this phrase commonly used in everyday spoken English?

Answer (score 4):

I have never come across " Thanks a pile " in the UK.

There are a whole bunch of very similar sayings: "thanks a million", "thanks a bunch", even: "thanks a lot"  but when written down they all suffer the same issue, which is that they are just as frequently used in a sarcastic manner, so you need to be VERY clear in your context that you mean it in a positive way.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer.